# Improve Duplicate check method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, duplicates

Morning guys.

Using C sharp .net4, and MS Visual Studio 2010.

I have Developed a duplication checker for my windows form program.
It works perfectly and Is virtually Instant on my Datagrid when there are a couple hundred records.

The problem I've noticed is that when there are 6000 records displayed it is not efficient enough at all and takes minutes.

I was wandering if anyone has some good tips to make this method a lot faster either improving upon the existing design or, a different method all together that I've over looked.

Your help is once again much appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
public void CheckForDuplicate()
{
    DataGridViewRowCollection coll = ParetoGrid.Rows;
    DataGridViewRowCollection colls = ParetoGrid.Rows;
    IList<String> listParts = new List<String>();
    int count = 0;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in coll)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow items in colls)
        {
            count++;
            if ((items.Cells["NewPareto"].Value != null) && (items.Cells["NewPareto"].Value != DBNull.Value))
            {
                if ((items.Cells["NewPareto"].Value != DBNull.Value) && (items.Cells["NewPareto"].Value != null) && (items.Cells["NewPareto"].Value.Equals(item.Cells["NewPareto"].Value)))
                {
                    if ((items.Cells["Part"].Value != DBNull.Value) && (items.Cells["Part"].Value != null) && !(items.Cells["Part"].Value.Equals(item.Cells["Part"].Value)))
                    {
                        listParts.Add(items.Cells["Part"].Value.ToString());

                        dupi = true; //boolean toggle
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }  
    MyErrorGrid.DataSource = listParts.Select(x => new { Part = x }).ToList();     
}
```

Any Questions let me know and I will do my best to answer them.

Comment: One simple optimisation that won't change your code much, don't look all columns twice, the outer loop loops all of them, the inner loop loops from where the outer loop is, to the end

Comment: In addition. Cells["NewPareto"]is a string lookup. What about you get the NUMBER once outside the loop (the tables wont change in the loop), then access via number?

Comment: yer the original reason is I loop through to get the 1st value, then using it as the base I check all other values via the second loop to see if there is a match.

Comment: @StevenSmith if you've looked at my answer I should add that I've just changed it for a much better solution that means you only do the cell lookups once for each row.

Comment: ah ill take a look that shud rocket down my time taken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, you should try and do this on the underlying data rather than on the UI objects - however I have a hunch that you're seeding it from a set of DataRows, in which case you might not be able to do that.

I think a big part of the issue here is the repeated dereferencing of the cells by name, and the fact that you repeatedly deference the second set of cells.  So do it all up front:

```
var first = (from row in coll.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            let newpareto = row.Cells["NewPareto"].Value ?? DBNull.Value
            let part = row.Cells["Part"].Value ?? DBNull.Value
            where newpareto != DBNull.Value && part != DBNull.Value
            select new 
            { newpareto = newpareto, part = part }).ToArray();

//identical - so a copy-paste job (if not using anonymous type we could refactor)
var second = (from row in colls.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            let newpareto = row.Cells["NewPareto"].Value ?? DBNull.Value
            let part = row.Cells["Part"].Value ?? DBNull.Value
            where newpareto != DBNull.Value && part != DBNull.Value
            select new 
            { newpareto = newpareto, part = part }).ToArray();


//now produce our list of strings
var listParts = (from f in first
                where second.Any(v => v.newpareto.Equals(f.newpareto)
                                   && !v.part.Equals(f.part))
                select f.part.ToString()).ToList(); //if you want it as a list.
```

Comment: to match the code in question, this should be `&& !part1.Equals(part2)`

Comment: ok i did some testing, 3 times with my version 3 times with yours.
Based upon 4832 records, mine takes 1 min 21 seconds to complete.
Yours takes 57 seconds to complete.  Thats great news as its shed a nice 24 seconds of the time, but still needs improving hehe

Comment: gona try your new solution looks alot faster!

Comment: let newpareto = row["NewPareto"].Value ?? DBNull.Value cannot apply indexing to [] expression of type windows.systems.datagridrow

Comment: offcourse, was wandering since ive never seen select or let in c sharp before, is it some form of sql in a 3rd gen langauge?

Comment: well it works, only its 1min 2 seconds, which is still faster than mine.  is there a way to implement the 1st solution and second? using objects inside the t-sql or whatever its called (have yet to look its name up hehe)

Comment: @StevenSmith it's called Linq - here are the 101 samples for it: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b.  This second attempt really shouldn't be slower because it's doing much less work.

Comment: @StevenSmith I've just realised why it's no faster - stick both linq statements in `()` and stick a `ToArray()` at the end of them.  It'll be miles faster

Answer (score 1):

There is an approach that will make this much more efficient. You need to compute a *hash* of each item. Items with different hashes can't possibly be duplicates.

Once you have the hashes, you could either sort by hash or use a data structure with efficient keyed retrieval (like `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`) to find all the duplicates.

Comment: Although I would agree in principle - it's not a trivial solution: How will you calculate hashes for those with null values in cells or DBNulls?  If you take the obvious approach and use `0` you can't implement the short-circuiting on the equality logic here where any cells with `null` or `DBNull.Value` are automatically ignored.  You'll end up forcing a dictionary to perform the more lengthy equality check for those rows because they'll share the same hash.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan yes, this algorithm requires that you perform the checks on some items that end up being different. That's its fundamental property. The improvement is still huge, because you no longer need to do 6000*6000/2 comparisons.

Comment: using hashes seesm very interesting, though ive never attempted it before and I'm a bit dubious about my skills to implement it into my code

Comment: There is another interesting gotcha with this, as well - one that I initially missed till Eren pointed it out on my first solution - the dupes here are actually when one field is equal and the other isn't - that's impossible to implement in a single hash.